# How to slowly migrate from Perforce to Git

Tags: git, perforce

I have a fairly big Perforce repository with around 1.5 million changelists and consider to migrate over to a Git server. I know some big companies did such transition as well (e.g Autodesk, Microsoft) with good success.

1) I prefer to transfer the old history over to Git as well but our current branch structure is very different to a modern Git model. How would you approach such transition?

2) Does it make sense to consider using a dual approach for a transition phase where devs can use Git or Perforce where each push/submit sis also pushed to the other repo system?

3) Which git server would you recommend from your experience? I saw Helix4Git is a Git server by Perforce. Would that be a suitable solution to start with?

Answer (score 3):

I have done it before, on a large team, big code base and a huge history.

1) Why? You will realize soon that you will not be looking at the history in Git, because you will always have your Perforce repo as a read-only (free of charge). But if you still care, you could use tools that will migrate the history for you.

2) No, not at all. You would not want each dev to do the work twice, commit twice, on two copies of the code, each is on a different version-control platform.

3) Any is fine. Github, Gitlab, Azure DevOps (MSTS).. whatever cheaper for you. Which server to use should not be your main issue. Your main issue should be the developers' transition from one VC mentality (Perforce - central) and tool-usage, commands.. etc, into a completely different VC mentality (Git - distributed) and tool-usage, commands.. etc

With large teams and big history, I would recommend:

- Do not manage two code bases at the same time, let the period of jumping ships be as small as possible (a weekend)
- Decide your process and agree on your branching structure before migrating, then train your team and prepare the documentation
- Leave the history behind. It can be migrated, but you won't need it

Comment: About 2) I was more referring to an approach where one push automatically pushes it to the other repository as well. We have a lot of tools that would all break on a hard transition

Comment: @DanielStephens I don't know such a proccess/script/approach, but in theory it will save only the step of "doing the work twice", but managing two code-bases on two different platforms is not a solution. How big is your history/team?

Comment: 150 devs, 1.5million code changes

Answer (score 2):

1. I would use my intelligence guided by experience -- that is to say, I would take what I knew about my branch structure and why it is the way it is, and then apply the logic used to build that structure in Perforce to build a structure in Git that accomplishes the same ends.
2. No.  Unidirectional migration is hard enough, bidirectional replication in real time is an impossibility.
3. Helix4Git does not (as of the last time I investigated it) provide any sort of functionality to migrate between the Perforce and Git data models, so I don't think there's any advantage to using it as part of a migration strategy.  IMO you should approach the general question of "how should I host my Git repos" independently of the Perforce migration question.

Comment: Thanks! There is no migration for git in Heix4Git but we have many devs and I fear that if there is a problem with the Git Server we can’t work anymore and we could use their support to either fix a bug or help with a support plan, would that make sense?

Comment: I would assume that most of the enterprise-level Git hosting solutions would also offer support contracts.  As far as I know Helix4Git does not have very wide usage yet and I'd personally be leery of being an early adopter at a large scale unless there were a compelling competitive advantage -- but again, "what git hosting solution should I use" is its entirely own question.  There are a LOT of options out there and I'm sure you can find exhaustive reviews of most of them.

Comment: Thank you! Hosting is not an option but your answer still helped a lot! Thanks!